# How to do Naive Bayes modelling (using sklearn MultinomialNB) in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am currently learning how to do Naive Bayes modelling and attempting to apply it in python and R however, using a toy example, I am struggling to recreate the same numbers in python that I get from doing the calculations in either R or by hand.

Help in figuring out why I am getting different numbers would be appreciated!

The toy data is

```
Class (y)   A A A A  B B B B B B
  var x1    2 1 1 0  0 1 1 0 0 0
  var x2    0 0 1 0  0 1 1 1 1 1
```

That is to say my dependent variable y has 2 levels  A & B,  explanatory variable x1 has 3 levels  0,1,2  and x2 has two levels 0 & 1.

My current objective is to predict, using a multinomial naivebayes model, the class probabilities of a new data point with values x1=1 & x2=1.

My current python code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

dat = pd.DataFrame({
    "class" : ["A", "A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B","B"],
    "x1" : [2,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
    "x2" : [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]
})

mnb = MultinomialNB(alpha= 0)
x = mnb.fit(dat[["x1","x2"]], dat["class"])
x.predict_proba(  pd.DataFrame( [[1,1]] , columns=["x1","x2"])   )

## Out[160]: array([[ 0.34325744,  0.65674256]])
```

However attempting the same in R I get:

```
library(dplyr)
library(e1071)    

dat = data_frame(
    "class" = c("A", "A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B","B"),
    "x1" = c(2,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),
    "x2" = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)
)

model <- naiveBayes(class ~ . , data = table(dat) )

predict(
    model, 
    newdata = data_frame(
        x1 = factor(1, levels = c(0,1,2)) ,
        x2 = factor(1, levels = c(0,1))),  
    type = "raw"
)
##             A         B
## [1,] 0.2307692 0.7692308
```

And by hand I get the following:

The model is

[image]

From the data we get the following probability estimates

[image]

Thus plugging the numbers in we get

[image]

Which matches the results from R. So again I'm confused as to what I am doing wrong in the python example. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me. As far as I can tell from that question/solution I have specified the data correctly. Thank you for the link though !